# page.goto (puppeteer) does not stop calling itself when opening the same url it is navigating to

Tags: express, puppeteer, html-to-pdf

I am trying to convert an html web page into a pdf file by using puppeteer. It is converting the html web page into pdf file but the problem is that, `page.goto` is not stopping after its job is done. When this happens, the terminal I run this localhost server from becomes a little unresponsive. I also deployed it on heroku but when I visit the url, the server responds me with error code 503 and it does not convert to pdf there.

```
let printPDF = async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/preview')
    await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' , path: `${__dirname}/contact.pdf`, printBackground: true});

    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
    console.log("repeat") //logging to see its repetition
  }

  catch (error) {
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
  }
}

getReviewPage = ((req, res) => {
    printPDF()
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/form.html`)
})

app.route('/preview').get(getReviewPage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `printPDF` is an async function returning Promise, you need to wait for it to finish, with `then` for example:

```
const getReviewPage = (req, res) => {
  printPDF().then(() => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/form.html`)
}
```

Comment: It solved the problem. Now I'll always remember that an async function returns a Promise. I am still learning. Thank you, sire. 